# Laravel 4 Ajax call dose not work getting redirected to action like normal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I am trying to submit a form via Ajax in my Laravel 4 App.

The problem: I just get redirected to the Route. So no Ajax call is send. The form just works like a normal form.

The Form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'ajax.profile.edit', 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'edit-profile' )) }}
```

The JS Code in my View:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $( '#edit-profile' ).on( 'submit', function() {
        //Form is located in a Modal, so first hide it
        $("#form-primary").niftyModal('hide');
        //Show a modal with a "loading" note
        $('#processing-modal').modal('show');

        $.post(
            $( this ).prop( 'action' ),
            {
                "_token": $( this ).find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val(),
                "displayname": $( '#displayname' ).val(),
                "bio": $( '#bio' ).val(),
                "expertise": $( '#expertise' ).val(),
                "location": $( '#location' ).val(),
            },
            function( data ) {
               //now hide the "loading" note and alter the success message.
                $('#processing-modal').modal('hide');
                alert(data.msg);
            },
            'json'
        );
        return false;
    } );

} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I use it in exactly the same manner (submitting a Laravel form via AJAX).

```
$('#edit-profile').submit(function (event) {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize()
        }).done(function (data) {

            // on success

        }).fail(function (data) {

            // on error

        });
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the form submitting in the traditional way. `event` is passed submit's callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $( '#edit-profile' ).on( 'submit', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        /* The rest of your code */


        return false;
    } );

});
```

Comment: Nope this dose not work. But i tried everything on a different view and its working fine. So i think i am using some JavaScript code in my View that breaks the Ajax calls...